# angular.js link behaviour - disable deep linking for specific URLs

Tags: angularjs

I have a working Angular.js app with HTML5 mode enabled.

```
$location.Html5mode(true).hashbang("!");
```

What I want to achieve is to get some URLs or `<a>` tags to do the normal browsing behaviour instead of changing the URL in the address bar using HTML5 history API and handling it using Angular controllers.

I have this links:

```
<a href='/auth/facebook'>Sign in with Facebook</a>
<a href='/auth/twitter'>Sign in with Twitter</a>
<a href='/auth/...'>Sign in with ...</a>
```

And I want the browser to redirect the user to `/auth/...` so the user will be then redirected to an authentication service.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Adding `target="_self"` works in Angular 1.0.1:

```
<a target="_self" href='/auth/facebook'>Sign in with Facebook</a>
```

This feature is documented (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location - search for '_self')

If you're curious, look at the angular source (line 5365 @ v1.0.1). The click hijacking only happens if `!elm.attr('target')` is true.

Comment: works with angular 1.2.16 and likely with current master https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/location.js#L687

Comment: had to use this to enable a transitioning period while converting rails routes to angular routes

Comment: This causes a full page reload for me when using Angular in conjunction with Turbolinks.

Answer (score 20):

An alternative to Fran6co's method is to disable the 'rewriteLinks' option in the $locationProvider:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    rewriteLinks: false
});
```

This will accomplish exactly the same thing as calling $rootElement.off('click'), but will not interfere with other javascript that handles click events on your app's root element.

See [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider), and [relevant source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/location.js#L843)

Comment: This doesn't work for me, but @Fran6co's [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11785196/295686) almost does (see my comment). I'm running it on a page that loads the app but no controller targets the tree that the anchor tag is in.

Comment: +1 for this answer. It wasn't until I enabled html5Mode on $locationProvider that the issue arose in the first place.

Answer (score 16):

This is the code for turning off deep linking all together. It disables the click event handler from the rootElement.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
   .run(['$location', '$rootElement', function ($location, $rootElement) {
      $rootElement.off('click');
}]);
```

Comment: This is a nice solution for a mixed MVC/Angular site where some links are to a mini-SPA which are intercepted by the Angular route config, yet other links are for regular MVC page requests. In my case the regular links worked until an Angular controller was loaded (when SPA was used), at which point the regular MVC links were hijacked and produced no response. So upvoted.

Comment: Whatever you put `$location` in you'll need to do this: e.g. a `.controller('fooController', function($location) { })` you'll need to remove events like `.controller('fooController', function($element, $location) { $element.off('click'); })`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using pushstate to set the url when applying filters on a page. With this I can use `$location.search()` and still have my `<a>`  tags function normally. (without having to apply `target="_self" everywhere`)

Comment: I ran into this with a mixed Angular and Node/Express app and this worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: This initially worked but upon further testing it created unexpected side effects. On a mixed Angular/pure jQuery page, a `<a href=#>` (outside an angular controller) with a jQuery `e.preventDefault()` used to work but now I encountered an error very similar to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1417) which sounded right - "$locationWatch expects the $location service to be updated first, followed by the browser. But when I pushState to the browser directly [or in my case navigate to #], the $location service still has the old url." I had to continue looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

To work off the Nik's answer, if you have lots of links and don't want to add targets to each one of them, you can use a directive:

```
Module.directive('a', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.attr("target", "_self");
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same issue a few times now with angular, and while I've come up with two functional solutions, both feel like hacks and not very "angular".

**Hack #1:**

Bind a `window.location` refresh to the link's `click` event.

```
<a 
  href=/external/link.html 
  onclick="window.location = 'http://example.com/external/link.html';"
>
```

The downside and problems with this approach are fairly obvious.

**Hack #2**

Setup Angular `$route`s that perform a `$window.location` change.

```
// Route
.when('/external', {
  templateUrl: 'path/to/dummy/template', 
  controller: 'external'
})

// Controller
.controller('external', ['$window', function ($window) {
  $window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
}])
```

I imagine that you could extend this using `$routeParams` or query strings to have one controller handle all "external" links.

As I said, neither of these solutions are very satisfactory, but if you must get this working in the short term, they might help.

On a side note, I would really like to see Angular support `rel=external` for this type of functionality, much like jQueryMobile uses it to disable ajax page loading.

Comment: I would like to see `rel=external` working too. Until then, I will use the **hack #2**. I will mark your answer as accepted shortly but I would like to wait a little longer to see if anyone solved this in a more _angular-ish way_. Thank you!

Comment: I had similar ideas, specifically using `$window.location` to force a page refresh in `html5mode = true`—this does not work properly in Webkit browsers; definitely use `target=_self`.

Answer (score 0):

In your routes try:

`$routeProvider.otherwise({})`

Comment: Doesn't work. Only if I use the External controller from Noah's answer.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Dragonfly's answer, a best practice I have found to limit the number of target="_self" attributes is to **never** put the ng-app attribute on the body tag. By doing that you are telling angular that **everything** within the body tags are a part of the angular app.

If you are working within a static wrapper that should not be affected by angular, put your ng-app attribute on a div (or other element) that surrounds only the location your angular app is going to be working in. This way you will only have to put the target='_self' attribute on links that will be children of the ng-app element.

```
<body>
    ... top markup ...
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    ... bottom markup ...
</body>
```