# How do I mix links that trigger page refreshes, with Angular's html5Mode = true without breaking the back button?

Tags: angularjs, routes, coffeescript, pushstate

I'll walk through the problematic flow...

- I load **google.com** (just as a starting point)
- I goto **app.com**
- I nav to **app.com/projects**
- I nav to **app.com/api/test** (through window.location)
- I see the raw JSON (good so far...)
- I press back, url changes to **app.com/projects** but I still see the JSON.
- I press back again, url changes to **app.com** but I still see the JSON.
- I press back again, **google.com** loads.
- I press forward, **app.com** loads fine... everything back to normal

What's odd, is I've observed this only when `html5Mode = true` in Webkit—*firefox works as desired*...

. . .

First, my **server.coffee** looks like this:

```
app.get '/partials/:partial', routes.partials
app.get '/api/test', api.test
app.get '*', routes.index
```

Basically, all requests load the index (which bootstraps Angular), with exception for a view/partial handler, and a test api route that responds with raw JSON.

. . .

(I'm using the [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) module for managing nested views and UI states; it uses `$urlRouterProvider`, which is very similar to Angular's `$routeProvider`)

Second, my **app.coffee** looks like this:

```
app = angular.module('app', ['ui-router'])
.config([
    '$stateProvider'
    '$locationProvider'
    '$urlRouterProvider'
    ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider)->
        $urlRouterProvider
            .when('/api/test', [
                '$window'
                '$location'
                ($window, $location)->
                    $window.location.href = '/api/test'
            ])
            .otherwise('/')
        $stateProvider
            .state 'home',
                url: '/'
                templateUrl: 'partials/index'
                controller: 'IndexCtrl'
            .state 'projects',
                url: '/projects'
                templateUrl: 'partials/projects'
                controller: 'ProjectsCtrl'
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix '!'
])
```

Since everything is async, I had to use `$window` to access `window.location.href` to trigger a page refresh so that the server would handle the route.

So my question, can I mix links that trigger page refreshes with Angular's `html5Mode` without breaking the back button? Is this just a Webkit bug, and/or is there a better way to do this?

Ideally, I'd have the application running off Angular—but things like the "about" or "contact" page (which have no need to be dynamic or async), would be served directly from the server using regular page refreshes...

Help!

Comment: Now that I have the answer, I found a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580004/angular-js-link-behaviour-disable-deep-linking-for-specific-urls

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Two options:

1. If you're using `<a />` tags, specify `target="_self"` to let AngularJS know it shouldn't capture their clicks (those links will be handled by browser normally). This is not a hack; this is normal documented behavior.
2. Use `$window.location = 'foo'` as you have been doing. That is acceptable.

Comment: +1 for option 1, that fixes the back button in webkit with `html5Mode = true`; I definitely missed that in the documentation, thanks Ezekiel!

Comment: Victor's solution works. Setting <code>target="_self"</code> forces a page reload than just routing.

Comment: Having to alter every single link on the rest of the site, including links that may be in content in the database, does not seem like an acceptable solution - there's got to be a better way!