# AngularJS view doesn't change when navigating to link

Tags: angularjs

I'm baffled by the following: I have a simple link like this:

```
    <li><a href="#/foo">Foos</a></li>
```

but when clicking on it, the view is not updated. The URL in the browser changes, but nothing happens, and nothing gets displayed in the console. If I load the URL directly in the browser, then the correct page is loaded.

The routes look like this:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, RestangularProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/index', {templateUrl: 'assets/views/index.html'})
        .when('/foos', {templateUrl: 'assets/views/list.html', controller: controllers.FooListCtrl})
        .when('/foos/create', {templateUrl: 'assets/views/update.html', controller: controllers.FooUpdateCtrl})
        .when('/foos/:id/update', {templateUrl: 'assets/views/update.html', controller: controllers.FooUpdateCtrl})
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/index'});

    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl("/admin");
});
```

Comment: did you try ng-href instead of href?

Comment: Yes, but without success

Comment: Any chance you can show some more of your code or even set up a plunkr where issue can be reproduced?

Comment: What do your routes look like?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so apparently, this is a [known issue of sorts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/angular/link%2420not%2420working/angular/BsenavakfyQ/wtbRBVBxJ0sJ): when the locationProvider (i.e. `$location`) is injected to one controller, links cease to work globally. One workaround seems to be to rewrite the links via jQuery, and that works:

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
    $('[ng-app]').on('click', 'a', function() {
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
    });
});
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you Sr.

Answer (score 3):

I have been able to resolve this issue by adding `target="_self"` to the link.

```
<li><a href="#/foo" target="_self">Foos</a></li>
```

I found this resolution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11857881/671817).