# Page only navigates when manually refreshing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I seem to be encountering a weird issue in a MEAN-stack app: An `anchor` link that should be navigating to another page doesn't do so. Instead, it changes the URL in the URL box, but the user has to manually refresh for the new page to show up.

`/routes/welcome.js` (Node.JS routing):

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
router.get("/welcome", function(req, res, next) {
    res.render("welcome", {title: "Express"});
});
module.exports = router;
```

`/landing.ejs` (This is the main page. User starts from here):

```
<html>
    ...
    <body ng-app="myapp">
        <div ui-view="container" class="head-container">
            <a href="/welcome">Login</a>
  ...
</html>
```

`authController.js`:

```
var app = angular.module(“myapp.controllers.auth", [
  "ui.router"
]);

app.config([
  "$stateProvider",
  function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("welcome", {
      parent: "root",
      url: "/welcome",
      templateUrl: "welcome",
      controller: "AuthController",
    })
  }
]);
```

Assuming the user is at `localhost:3000` and is currently looking at the `landing.ejs` page. If he/she clicks on the "login" link, the URL in the URL box changes to `localhost:3000/welcome`, but the actual page remains the same, as if nothing happened. But when the user right clicks and refreshes the page, it changes to `welcome.ejs`. Why do I have to refresh?

Comment: Is there anything in the chrome dev console? You may also want to try <a href="/#!/welcome">Login</a> (with the /#!/ before the url)

Comment: What do you try to achieve here? You have a server side route `/welcome` and a client side route `/welcome`... If you want to navigate to the state `welcome` in the angular app you have to navigate to `#welcome`

Comment: Server side routing is not really needed here, I just added it in order to avoid the "you didn't give enough info" comment. There are two sorts of navigation going on, one that is embedded inside the existing page, other that is navigation between different pages (like google.com to yahoo.com). I am trying to achieve the latter here.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<a ui-sref="welcome">Login</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="/welcome">Login</a>
```

Comment: That gives a weird `Error: Could not resolve '/welcome' from state ''` in the console.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `$locationProvider` was messing with the links. [As stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17838468/1079641), there is a known issue with links and `$locationProvider`.