# Angular routes - redirecting to an external site?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

In an AngularJS routes file there is the option for an `otherwise` route, replacing a 404:

```
$routeProvider
.when(...)
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: 'my/path'
});
```

Is there a way to do this such that the otherwise redirects to a page that is not in the app? I tried

```
$routeProvider
.when(...)
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: 'http://example.com'
});
```

but this jsut tried to redirect to that path in my app, which doesn't exist. The solution I know of is to do manual redirection in a `$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart')` in a top-level controller, but this is a lot of code duplication (and it's ugly). Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To my [knowledge](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24routeProvider), this is not possible, as the `routeProvider` handles internal routes only.

What you can do though is

```
$routeProvider
.when(...)
.otherwise({
    controller: "404Controller",
    template: "<div></div>"
});
```

and then just use `window.location.href = 'http://yourExternalSite.com/404.html'` in the controller.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, this worked for me:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/my-path', {
    ...typical settings...
}).
.otherwise({
        redirectTo: function(obj, requestedPath) {
            window.location.href = appConfig.url404;
        }
});
```

Comment: This fix worked for me (redirect to non-angular resource on the same host)

Answer (score 5):

Just take a look at [angular.js link behaviour - disable deep linking for specific URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580004/angular-js-link-behaviour-disable-deep-linking-for-specific-urls)

and use this

> target="_self"

```
<a href="link" target="_self" >link</a>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. Works on angular 1.5

Answer (score 2):

I won't recommend just using window.location.href in new controller as pointed in other answer because the ngRoute would have set the history to be pointing at the non-existent page (so when user clicks back it will keep redirecting to the 404 page). I tried and it failed.

I would like to point you to my related solution to another SO question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27938693/1863794

I adopted that and applied to your scenario. I don't think it's that bad of an idea to use `MainCtrl` outside of the ng-view since it'll be only declared once unless you have nested layers of ng-view... I don't see any code duplication either, you can place MainCtrl in a separate module if it bothers you so much:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when(..) 
  .otherwise({redirectTo: 'http://yourExternalSite.com/404.html'}); 
}])
.controller('MainCtrl',[ // <- Use this controller outside of the ng-view!
  '$rootScope','$window',
  function($rootScope,$window){
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
      // next.$$route <-not set when routed through 'otherwise' since none $route were matched
      if (next && !next.$$route) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Stops the ngRoute to proceed with all the history state logic
        // We have to do it async so that the route callback 
        // can be cleanly completed first, so $timeout works too
        $rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {
          // next.redirectTo would equal be 'http://yourExternalSite.com/404.html'
          $window.location.href = next.redirectTo;
        });
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

Cheers