# Using $routeProvider to redirect to routes outside of Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've written part of a web application in Angular. To ensure that all routes are covered, I wanted to add a `redirectTo` property to the `$routeProvider`, so that invalid routes are returned to the root of the web application, which doesn't use Angular.

I tried:

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});
```

but obviously this only routes in the Angular controlled portion of the URL, so users would be redirected to a URL like `http://app.com/angular-part-of-web-app#`, instead of `http://app.com`, where I'd like them to go.

I've worked around this by having a blank partial to act as a '404' page, and then a controller which just uses the `$window` object to redirect to the desired page:

**routes.js**

```
// Redirect to site list.
$routeProvider.when('/404', {
    templateUrl: '/partials/404.html',
    controller: 'RedirectCtrl'
});

// Redirect to the 404 page.
$routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/404'
});
```

**controllers.js**

```
// Controller to redirect users to root page of site.
.controller('RedirectCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) {

    $window.location.href = '/';
}]);
```

However, this is setting off the 'too hacky, must be a better way' alarm bells. Is there a better way to do this in Angular?

EDIT: [Angular routes - redirecting to an external site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131099/angular-routes-redirecting-to-an-external-site?rq=1) didn't yield an answer to the same question. I'm going to leave my question open instead of marking it as a duplicate (for now), as with the Angular world moving so fast, the previous answer may no longer be the case.

Comment: Probably handle it on the server-side of things.

Comment: I am also looking to solve this. I'm in the process of switching my app to Angular and have some parts that are still served from the server. Need to find a way to connect between the Angular part and the non-Angular part

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The above solution with /404 does not work for me.
This however seems to work

```
.otherwise({
    controller : function(){
        window.location.replace('/');
    }, 
    template : "<div></div>"
});
```

PS. I am using Angular 1.2.10

Comment: I'm also using Angular 1.2 and the accepted answer didn't work but this one did.  The template was necessary too.

Comment: if you need to navigate somewhere else instead of root of your domain you may need hash `#` ,slashes `/` and/or some `a` anchor names, because of using `window.location` method.

Answer (score 19):

You could do something like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/404', {
    controller: ['$location', function($location){
        $location.replace('/');
    }]
}).otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/404'
});
```

It is essentially the same thing, only it uses less code.

Comment: I didn't realise controllers could be declared inline like that. That's very cool, thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Not sure what version of Angular JS the accepted answer was written on, but 'redirectTo' property takes in a function. So, why not do something simpler like this:

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: function() {
        window.location = "/404.html";
    }
});
```

Obviously, you have to create your own 404.html. Or wherever your 404 page is.

Comment: How do you pass the current path to the redirectTo function?

Comment: You can get the current URL in JavaScript with `document.URL`

Comment: document.location.pathname is probably the best option to get the path

Comment: `window.location.replace` is cleaner as it replaces the bad url in the browser history and prevents any back button loop c**p

Answer (score 5):

None of the answers including the marked answer worked for me. I believe my solution solves your problem as well and I'd share my use-case as well for future readers' reference.

**Issue with using the route controller method:**
When the controller is loaded the routing already have accessed the History API states for me (I use HTML5 mode, not sure whether this affects non-HTML5 mode).

As a result, even though I can forward people to the correct page using 
    window.location.replace('/');, 
if the user then clicks Back on their browser, it goes to invalid state.

**Scenario:** We implement multi-page model and I have my admin page module separate from my homepage (non-admin) modules. I have a $location.path('/') somewhere in one of my admin controller, but since homepage isn't packaged into the admin page module, I want to force full page reload when I detect the '/' route.

**Solution:** 
We have to intercept at the $routeChangeStart before ngRoute accesses any of the state info. This way we can even specify external href by passing url to redirectTo param in the $route

```
angular.module('app',['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/admin/default', {template: somePageTemplate})
  /*
   *  More admin-related routes here...
   */
  .when('/',{redirectTo:'/homepage'})  // <-- We want to intercept this
  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/admin/default'}); 
}])
.controller('MainCtrl',[ // <- Use this controller outside of the ng-view!
  '$rootScope','$window',
  function($rootScope,$window){
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
      // next <- might not be set when first load
      // next.$$route <- might not be set when routed through 'otherwise'
      // You can use regex to match if you have more complexed path...
      if (next && next.$$route && next.$$route.originalPath === '/') {
        // Stops the ngRoute to proceed
        event.preventDefault();
        // We have to do it async so that the route callback 
        // can be cleanly completed first, so $timeout works too
        $rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {
          // next.$$route.redirectTo would equal be '/homepage'
          $window.location.href = next.$$route.redirectTo;
        });
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

Please provide any feedback as I will be using this code myself.
Cheers

**Reference:**
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9607

Answer (score 3):

Hi even though it's been two years, just for some one who search for this answer, simply use window.location.assign('/login'). It's work for me.

Comment: That sounds good - I just looked up the difference between `location.assign` and `location.replace` and found a good answer, if anybody's interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505798/difference-between-window-location-assign-and-window-location-replace