# Redirect to URL if routing is not available in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I am using AngularJS routing for 4 pages for example a,b,c and d but in that page there're lots of link like e,f,g,h

What I want is if I write routing condition for page then it should do routing but if any other link comes like e or f then it should redirect it to particular link like `window.top.location = e` because otherwise it show blank pages and search for template

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/a', {
        templateUrl: base_url+'a.html',
        controller: 'a'
      })
      .when('/b', {
        templateUrl: base_url+'b.html',
        controller: 'b'
      })
      .when('/c', {
        templateUrl: base_url+'c.html',
        controller: 'c'
      })
      .when('/d', {
        templateUrl: base_url+'d.html',
        controller: 'd'
      }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: LINK_IN_WHICH_USER_CLICK;
      });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}])
```

now the issue is with current code is I am not getting url in which user clicked and 2nd issue is I want it to redirect like `window.top.location` so that it refreshed properly and don't show blank page

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, are you asking how to have angular `redirectTo` non-angular pages? because the only way that angular is going to try to route to a route in the RouteProvider is when you supply relative URLs in your `href=`.  if you provide a full URL, then the RouteProvider never deals with the link at all.

Comment: Actually I have big project which have many pages and links but only 1 section requires routing so in that section I use routing but its having issue when trying to redirect on other pages which is not a part of routing but I am using angular in all pages

Comment: that still doesn't make sense.  are the other pages each their own app then, if they aren't handled by the RouteProvider?

Comment: ok but that's how my application is working so is there any solution for situation like that ?

Comment: so is that a yes, the additional pages are each their own app?

Comment: yes using the different app

Comment: ok, so if those routes need to be handled by the server, and you must use relative URLs, and HTML5Mode, you don't have a lot of options.  I'm not sure the correct syntax in this case, but I'll see what I can find.

Comment: pretty sure this will have the answer; it says "redirect outside angular".... technically, you are trying to redirect outside this angular app into another angular app, so it's appropriate in this case.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321765/using-routeprovider-to-redirect-to-routes-outside-of-angular

Comment: well got my answer its HTML attribute target="_self" which forcely redirect