# How to add external link to Angular SPA Menu?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hottowel

I'm using angular hottowel template for develop my web application. route config code file shown bellow.

```
(function(){  
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app');

// Collect the routes
app.constant('routes', getRoutes());

// Configure the routes and route resolvers
app.config(['$routeProvider', 'routes', routeConfigurator]);

function routeConfigurator($routeProvider, routes)
{
    routes.forEach(function(r)
    {
        setRoute(r.url, r.config);
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

    function setRoute(url, definition)
    {
        definition.resolve = angular.extend(definition.resolve || {}, {
            prime: prime
        });

        $routeProvider.when(url, definition);
    }
}

prime.$inject = ['datacontext'];
function prime(dc) { return dc.prime(); }

// Define the routes 
function getRoutes()
{
    return [
        {
            url: '/',
            config: {
                templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.html',
                title: 'dashboard',
                settings: {
                    nav: 1,
                    content: '<i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard'
                }
            }
        }, {
            url: '/customers',
            config: {
                title: 'customers',
                templateUrl: 'app/customer/customers.html',
                settings: {
                    nav: 2,
                    content: '<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> customers'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            url: '/customer/:id',
            config: {
                title: 'customer',
                templateUrl: 'app/customer/customerdetail.html',
                settings: {}
            }
        }
    ];
}})();
```

I need to add external link to my menu as example www.google.com. how can i add another link to this route config like bellow.

```
{
        url: 'www.google.com',
        config: {
            title: 'MyExternalLink',
            settings: {}
        }
    }
```

Comment: `<a href="http://www.google.com"></a>`

Comment: adding protocol will navigate to out .right?

Comment: Nikhil its not working

Comment: To where its navigating with protocol added urls?

Comment: this is the code i'm following https://github.com/leniel/SPACodeCamper

Answer (score 0):

This question looks similar to this post have a look
[Using $routeProvider to redirect to routes outside of Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321765/using-routeprovider-to-redirect-to-routes-outside-of-angular)

Comment: here i need to add more than one external links

Comment: This solution is not valid for my question