# External pages and Angular JS routing

Tags: angularjs, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a PHP page over at `mysite.com/somedir/script.php`.

When I have `<a>` tags in my Angular views that point to this script, Angular's routing always brings me back to `mysite.com/index.html` when I click on them.

This is my `$routeProvider` configuration:

```
siteModule.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl:'/views/blog.html',
            controller:'blogController'
        })
        .when('/blog',{
            templateUrl:'/views/blog.html',
            controller:'blogController'
        })
        .when('/work',{
            templateUrl:'/views/work.html',
            controller:'workController'
        });
    // For Pretty URLs
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

I'm also using some Apache `mod_rewrite` to handle 404s / page refreshes in an .htacess file that I think may be interfering:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
```

The aforementioned PHP page is a valid (existing) resource so I'm not sure why Angular or Apache would redirect / rewrite away from it. I'm using the `target="_blank"` on the `<a>` tags and have the `<base href="/">` set in the index page's `<head>` tag as well.

I just want to be able to access my script normally instead of being pointed back to the index page.

Comment: please post an example of an `a` anchor with a link that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can still use `window.location.href` to escape the router, so in the 'otherwise' section of your router, use `window.location.href` = {the route} instead of allowing it to use the default index.

See these other answers to this question:

[Angular routes - redirecting to an external site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131099/angular-routes-redirecting-to-an-external-site)

[Using $routeProvider to redirect to routes outside of Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321765/using-routeprovider-to-redirect-to-routes-outside-of-angular)