# Can't download a csv file via javascript click

Tags: javascript

I am trying to download a file by clicking a button but instead of getting my file as "myFile.csv" the file that returns is called "download" without any extension. I have tried the following solution as well [Download text/csv content as files from server in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904151/download-text-csv-content-as-files-from-server-in-angular)

This is server response

```
            var result = engine.WriteString(recs);
            response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result)) };
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = String.Format("TVF_Export_{0}.csv", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())
            };
            return response;
```

Client code

```
        $http.post(url, filters).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');

        hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/csv,' + encodeURI(data);
        hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
        hiddenElement.download = 'myFile.csv';
        hiddenElement.click();


    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('[DEBUG] error ' + data);
    });
```

Comment: Some more information would be useful. Where are you downloading your file from, what http-headers are set from the server-side?

Comment: the data object is just a string content

Comment: That's not what is important. You have to tell us, how the server responds to your download request. What HTTP headers are sent to you from the server? Normally it's the HTTP-headers that control such stuff

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over server response, then you can ensure the following header is set in response:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myFile.csv;
```

You should also specify `Content-Type: text/csv` or this:

```
Content-Type: application/force-download
```

Comment: What would your client code look like for a POST header verb?