# Download in browser with ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, angularjs, fpdf

I'm working with AngularJS and I'm trying to generate a PDF in php. This is what I have in my *controller.js*:

```
$scope.downloadPDF = function(){
    $http.post('/download-pdf', { fid: $routeParams.fid })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log("success");
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log("error");
        });
};
```

In my php file I have the following to create a PDF with [FPDF library](http://www.fpdf.org/):

```
function download_pdf()
{
    $id = $_POST['fid'];

    $pdf = new FPDF();

    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');

    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $id . '.pdf');

    $pdf->Output('Order123.pdf', 'D');
}
```

But the request is responding this instead of open a save dialog to save my pdf.

> %PDF-1.3
>       3 0 obj
>       <>
>       endobj
>       4 0 obj
>       <>
>       stream
>       x3Rðâ2Ð35W(çr
>       QÐw3T04Ó30PISp
>           êZ*[¤(hx¤æää+çå¤(j*dÔ7W
>       endstream
>       endobj
>       1 0 obj
>       <
>       endobj
>       5 0 obj
>       <
>       endobj
>       2 0 obj
>       <<
>       /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
>       /Font <<
>       /F1 5 0 R
>   >
>       /XObject <<
>   >
>   >
>       endobj
>       6 0 obj
>       <<
>       /Producer (FPDF 1.7)
>       /CreationDate (D:20150611094522)
>   >
>       endobj
>       7 0 obj
>       <<
>       /Type /Catalog
>       /Pages 1 0 R
>   >
>       endobj
>       xref
>       0 8
>       0000000000 65535 f 
>       0000000228 00000 n 
>       0000000416 00000 n 
>       0000000009 00000 n 
>       0000000087 00000 n 
>       0000000315 00000 n 
>       0000000520 00000 n 
>       0000000595 00000 n 
>       trailer
>       <<
>       /Size 8
>       /Root 7 0 R
>       /Info 6 0 R
>   >
>       startxref
>       644
>       %%EOF

I've used the [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) library and this worked:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($ea, 'Excel2007');

// We'll be outputting an excel file
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');

// It will be called Submission on [date_now].xls
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '.xls' . '"');

// Write file to the browser
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Now how can I make this work for my PDF?

**UPDATE:**

I've edited my code to this:

```
$pdf = new FPDF();

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');

$filename = DXS_VKGROUP_PLUGIN_LIB_DIR . 'uploads/' . $_POST['fid'] . '.pdf';

$pdf->Output($filename, 'F'); // Save file locally

header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Content-Type: application-download');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');

$handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
fpassthru($handle);
fclose($handle);
```

The file is saved locally but the download doesn't work. It doesn't get my a dialog to save the pdf. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 2**

I've now tried to change `application-download` in `application/pdf`. He saves the file locally but I don't get a download dialog box.

The response looks like this (when I check *Network* in Chrome):

> %PDF-1.3
>       3 0 obj
>       <>
>       endobj
>       4 0 obj
>       <>
>       stream
>       x3Rðâ2Ð35W(çr
>       QÐw3T04Ó30PISp
>           êZ*[¤(hx¤æää+çå¤(j*dÔ7W
>       endstream
>       endobj
>       1 0 obj
>       <
>       endobj
>       5 0 obj
>       <
>       endobj
>       2 0 obj
>       <<
>       /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
>       /Font <<
>       /F1 5 0 R
>   >
>       /XObject <<
>   >
>   >
>       endobj
>       6 0 obj
>       <<
>       /Producer (FPDF 1.7)
>       /CreationDate (D:20150617090832)
>   >
>       endobj
>       7 0 obj
>       <<
>       /Type /Catalog
>       /Pages 1 0 R
>   >
>       endobj
>       xref
>       0 8
>       0000000000 65535 f 
>       0000000228 00000 n 
>       0000000416 00000 n 
>       0000000009 00000 n 
>       0000000087 00000 n 
>       0000000315 00000 n 
>       0000000520 00000 n 
>       0000000595 00000 n 
>       trailer
>       <<
>       /Size 8
>       /Root 7 0 R
>       /Info 6 0 R
>   >
>       startxref
>       644
>       %%EOF

Comment: If your web browser settings doesn't have "Ask where to save each file before downloading" (Chrome) option or similar(Firefox - Always ask where to save files) ticked , then the browser won't show the Save As dialog even if you set the header of the file as `application-download` or `Content-Disposition: attachment` . The file will start downloading automatically. Something like https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js might be helpful in this case

Comment: What happens if you use `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');` instead of `application/pdf` ?

Comment: @Darren I checked , that too leads to file download process starting automatically without any prompt to save it

Comment: Did you try: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904151/download-text-csv-content-as-files-from-server-in-angular) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300547/download-csv-file-from-web-api-in-angular-js)?

Comment: Why did you let the bounty expire? Are none of the answers useful, or ... ?

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**

The method of using FileSaver.js also doesn't work , there seems to be no way to forcefully invoke the native Save As Dialog via JavaScript alone , only exception being the saveAs `execCommand` for IE. Check [Does execCommand SaveAs work in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833015/does-execcommand-saveas-work-in-firefox/833024)

<strike>Include [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) as dependency in your project</strike>

Change the `downloadPDF` function as follows

```
 $scope.downloadPDF = function() {
    $http.post('/download-pdf', {
        fid: $routeParams.fid
      }, {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
      })
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // Convert response data to Blob
        var file = new Blob([data], {
          type: 'application/pdf'
        });
        // Call the File Saver method to save the above Blob,this will show Save As dialog
        saveAs(file, "test.pdf");
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("error");
      });

 };
```

The `Blob` object will work in most modern browser but there is limited support for IE < 10 , check https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js#supported-browsers for polyfills

Also remove `Content-Disposition: attachment` and `Content-Type: application-download` headers as we don't want browser to natively handle the download process

Here is a working demo http://plnkr.co/edit/9r1tehQ94t5vkqZfZuQC?p=preview , it shows GET request to a PDF

Comment: Tried the demo: no Save As in Chrome, just direct download

Comment: This answer just mentions what doesn't work, why is it still getting so many up-votes?

Answer (score 3):

Let me suggest you one thing.

By AJAX only you cannot download any file. **You need to create .zip file first with ajax call and after that gaining that file path you have to open that file using any command.**

Here one example that works for me: :)

```
$http.post('www.abc.com/zipcreate', {'id': id}).then(function (zipurl) {
                    $window.location = zipurl;
            });
```

Surely, It works. Try once. :)

## **EDIT:**

Or you can use

```
$window.location = 'abc.com/link';
```

**in 'abc.com/link' :** 
use below code:

```
  header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$name);
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
  header("Expires: 0");
  readfile($file);
  exit;
```

You will get your file in download-list.

Comment: Why would they need to create a zip file? Wouldn't that make it harder for the user to actually open the document?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm) you can set the 2nd parameter to `D`:

```
$pdf->Output('Order123.pdf', 'D');
```

If you want to handle all the details yourself using a saved file, this is how I've presented PDFs to the browser for download from PHP:

```
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Content-Type: application-download');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('file.pdf'));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
$handle = fopen('file.pdf', 'rb');
fpassthru($handle);
fclose($handle);
```

Update:

Please verify that the PDF file is actually being made. Does the web server process have write access to that path? Is FPDF being included properly? I made this on a test VM and it presented a file `1.pdf` for download, which opened and contained "Hello World!":

```
<?php

require('/var/www/html/fpdf17/fpdf.php');

$_POST = array('fid' => '1');

$pdf = new FPDF();

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
$pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Hello World!');

$filename = '/tmp/' . $_POST['fid'] . '.pdf';

$pdf->Output($filename, 'F'); // Save file locally

header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Content-Type: application-download');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"');

$handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
fpassthru($handle);
fclose($handle);

unlink($filename);

?>
```

Comment: I've tried the D parameter, my topic was wrong. But still outputting the same as stated in topic.

Comment: In that case, try with the `F` parameter to save a local file, then pass that file to the browser then way I showed. At the end you can use `unlink($filename);` to remove it.

Comment: Try `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"');` because you cannot use a filename with a full folder path. Do you send any headers to the browser prior to that code?

Comment: Stil same result. No I don't send any headers to the browser prior .. Tried in firefox/chrome

Comment: The file does get saved and I can see and open it (when I don't unlink it). But the browser doesn't open a download dialog ... .

Comment: Try to change Content-type to application/pdf

Comment: Still the same, I've updated my topic. Sorry for editing your post. Was editing wrong ..

Comment: Using that last set of headers in my answer, both Firefox 34 and IE 11 present a Save As option, just Chrome doesn't seem to and proceeds to save automatically, perhaps that is it's only behavior and I've read around that others also have this issue.

Comment: Just saw Chrome has an option in it's settings to ask where to download: chrome://settings/search#download

Answer (score 2):

With ajax it is not possible.
Instead what you can do is, hit your action through javascript form submit.

e.g., `document.getElementById(formID).action= actionName`.

```
document.getElementById(formID).submit();
```

Here the formID is your form's id and the `actionName` will be `'/download-pdf'` as you have specified.

In your action class -  set response headers

```
getResponse().setContentType("application/pdf");
getResponse().setHeader("Content-Disposition",  " attachment; filename= "+"pdffile.pdf");
```

This will cause your file to be downloaded with filename = pdffile.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\"");
```

Or using BLOB:

```
 $scope.downloadPDF = function() {
    $http.post('/download-pdf', {
        fid: $routeParams.fid
      }, {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
      })
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        var file = new Blob([data], {
          type: 'application/pdf'
        });
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.location.href = url;
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("error");
      });

 };
```

Or create a element with `download` attribute:

```
$scope.downloadPDF = function() {
    $http.get('http://46.101.139.188/demo.pdf', {
      }, {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
      })
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        var file = new Blob([data], {
          type: 'application/pdf'
        });
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.setAttribute('download', 'download');
        a.setAttribute('href', url);

         var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
          'view': window,
          'bubbles': true,
          'cancelable': true
        });
        a.dispatchEvent(event);
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("error");
      });
 };
```

[plnkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Jti29maX8wjkZCP37p8y?p=preview)

Comment: Wouldn't the URL become too long for big PDF documents? Did you test it?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with (only) AJAX.

There are two main techniques you could use here, both *without* using JavaScript to perform the actual download. The general idea is that you redirect the browser to a resource that will provide the desired document; if you're redirecting to a download it will not leave the page but show the Save dialog instead. A similar topic is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830309/download-file-using-an-ajax-request).

#### GET Request

```
location.href = '/download-pdf?fid=' + encodeURIComponent($routeParams.fid);
```

Adjust your server-side script to use `$_GET['fid']`.

#### POST Request

The server creates a resource and responds with a URL where the resource can be found:

```
$http.post('/download-pdf', { fid: $routeParams.fid })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // follow location provided by server
        location.href = data.redirect_url;
        console.log("success");
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.log("error");
    });
```

Adjust your server-side script to return an appropriate JSON response after creating the new resource.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in the following manner and it works well for me:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#generaPdf').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var name = $('#name').val();
            $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "pdf.php",
                    data: { "name": name },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("todo ok")
                        location.href = "pdf.php"
                        // $('.result').html(data);
                        // $('#contactform')[0].reset();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

My html:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="generaPdf"><i class="fas fa-link"></i> Generar documento para impresión</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Send the document to a given destination: browser, file or string. In the case of browser, the plug-in may be used (if present) or a download ("Save as" dialog box) may be forced.

The method first calls Close() if necessary to terminate the document.

**Parameters**

***name:***

The name of the file. If not specified, the document will be sent to the browser (destination I) with the name doc.pdf.

***dest***

Destination where to send the document. It can take one of the following values:

- **I:** send the file inline to the browser. The plug-in is used if
  available. The name given by name is used when one selects the "Save
  as" option on the link generating the PDF.
- **D:** send to the browser and force a file download with the name given
  by name.
- **F:** save to a local file with the name given by name (may
  include a path).
- **S:** return the document as a string. name is ignored.