# Download text/csv content as files from server in Angular not working in Mozilla FireFox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, csv, firefox

[Download text/csv content as files from server in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904151/download-text-csv-content-as-files-from-server-in-angular)

Answered By - https://stackoverflow.com/users/2064206/dcodesmith

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
     anchor.attr({
         href: 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(data),
         target: '_blank',
         download: 'filename.csv'
     })[0].click();

  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // if there's an error you should see it here
  });
```

I implemented this solution for downloading files from server to client using angular. This is perfectly **working fine in Google chrome**. But this Solution is **not working in Mozilla Firefox**.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to attach the anchor you created to your document first. Add the followings:

```
var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
anchor.css({display: 'none'}); // Make sure it's not visible
angular.element(document.body).append(anchor); // Attach to document

anchor.attr({
    href: 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(data),
    target: '_blank',
    download: 'filename.csv'
})[0].click();

anchor.remove(); // Clean it up afterwards
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zpb1jnr/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `encodeURIComponent()` instead of `encodeURI()` - because of better encoding of characters like #, &, =. See documentation on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 0):

Just to recap, the solution that worked for me is (using encodeURIComponent as maciejlesniak suggested):

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
anchor.css({display: 'none'}); // Make sure it's not visible
angular.element(document.body).append(anchor); // Attach to document

anchor.attr({
    href: 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data),
    target: '_blank',
    download: 'filename.csv'
})[0].click();

anchor.remove(); // Clean it up afterwards

  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // if there's an error you should see it here
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also work around something like this.

```
var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
anchor.attr({
  href: 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(data),
  target: '_blank',
  download: 'filename.csv'
});
var click = new MouseEvent('click', {
      'view': window,
      'bubbles': true,
      'cancelable': true
  }); 
anchor[0].dispatchEvent(click);
```

This should work Firefox as well, without attaching the anchor tag on the document.body