# Angular - Save incoming file in response to $resource request

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular service. I am sending a request using $resource to my API. The API is sending a file which is supposed to be downloaded. How do I save it?

**NOTE:** My API is already sending headers which make the browser download the file.

If I access the API directly from browser, the file downloads. BUT, If I access the API from $resource, nothing happens.

**API:**

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    "content-disposition": "attachment;"
});
res.end(fileText);
```

Comment: What request type is it? If it's GET, try to use download attribute to a link.

Comment: GET, POST neither worked. Download attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I've found a total working solution for this, and unlike the old answer, it works on FF and IE:

```
var blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'text/json'});

// FOR IE:
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob);
}

// For Other browsers (tested on Chrome, FF)
else{
    var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
        a = document.createElement('a');

    a.download = filename;
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.dataset.downloadurl = ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':');
    e.initEvent('click', true, false, window,
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(e);
}
```

**Old answer:**

Thanks to **[topless](https://stackoverflow.com/users/226394/topless)** for guiding me to a proper answer. Here's how I got it working:

```
myService.exportData().$promise.then(function (response) {
    var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
    anchor.attr({
        href: 'data:attachment/json,' + encodeURI(JSON.stringify(response)),
        target: '_blank',
        download: 'exported logs.log'
    })[0].click();

})
```

Also, Now I dont need to set the headers at the API side.
`res.send(myFileText)` works just fine!

**NOTE: DOES NOT WORK IN IE & SAFARI**

Comment: The only problem is that it will not work in IE and Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Try providing a filename, if its a `json` type otherwise alter `content-type` accordingly.

```
"Content-Type": 'application/json'
"content-disposition": "attachment;filename=fname.json"
```

Comment: No, still nothing. It works if accessed directly from browser without giving filename

Comment: Can you give a try to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904151/download-text-csv-content-as-files-from-server-in-angular) or even better the more elegant and simple answer like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836273/export-javascript-data-to-csv-file-without-server-interaction)?

Comment: I am trying a Blob solution, but that doesn't seem a proper way to go. Will give this a try too