# Angularjs ui-router blocking access to non-state routes

Tags: angularjs, web, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router in an angular site I'm making, but cant get it to allow routes through to my server. I have facebook oauth authentication on my server, where I navigate to `/auth/facebook`and the server will redirect to fb, intercept the callback and redirect the client back to the homepage.

It works fine when navigating to the `/auth/facebook` url in a browser it works fine, but ui-router watches location and intercepts all of my location changes.

Any ideas how I can make a url request bypass the `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(...)` statement to allow a route through to my api server? I've tried adding route redirects with the router provider, but it won't trigger a remote call.

Comment: What's the full url in both cases.

Comment: its a local url so right now I'm on a development server so its 'http://localhost:9000/auth/facebook' ui-router states are in the form 'http://localhost:9000/about'. Also, it works fine if I just disable html5 mode.

Comment: Yeah, HTML5 mode would've been my next question. Angular removes the hash bang, turning `index.html#/about/facebook` into `/about/facebook`. If you wish to keep it, you may be able to do something with server side access like htaccess. Otherwise, maybe angulars onroutechange events?

Comment: Yeah, I may just opt for turning of html5 mode, but I feel like there should be a way to force a specific route to load from the server

Comment: Try setting the link to the full url instead of the short one `localhost:9000/auth/facebook` instead of '/auth/facebook'. Your server still knows wether or not you're requesting index.html

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but ui-router seems to intercept all location changes before querying the server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56157/discussion-between-jorg-and-micah-rosales).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to the guys at [angular-dart](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/335): As a workaround you could create an ng-click handler that does `window.location.assign('/auth/facebook')` to bypass the router

Comment: using `ng-click` wasn't working for me so I just made `ng-click` call a function on my scope which called `$window.location.assign('/auth/' + provider);`

Answer (score 3):

You can handle such requests in your app config with [$urlRouterProvider](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#urlrouterprovider):

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/auth/:provider', function() {
  window.location.reload();
});
```

Second solution:
Add `target="_self"` to your link like this:

```
<a target="_self" ng-href="{{'/auth/'+provider}}">{{provider}}</a>
```

Duplicate of: [angular.js link behaviour - disable deep linking for specific URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580004/angular-js-link-behaviour-disable-deep-linking-for-specific-urls)