# Unit test directive with $window and $event in Angular

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a super simple directive that overrides click behavior and does a full page reload on click. I'm having trouble writing a Unit Test for this directive. It looks like the `$window` doesn't get injected properly as well as this error when running the test:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$event.preventDefault')
```

**reload.directive.js**

```
 angular.module('myModule')
    .directive('reload', ['$window', function($window) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: '<a ng-click="reload($event)" ng-transclude></a>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.reload = function($event) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $window.location.href = attrs.href;
          };
        }
      };
    }]);
```

**An example of how I'm using it**

```
<a ui-sref="home", reload>Home Example</a>
```

**Here is my unit test: reload-test.directive.js**

```
describe('Testing reload directive', function() {
  beforeEach(module('myModule'));

  var window, element, scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $window) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    window = $window;
    element = $compile('<a reload href="/"></a>')(scope);
    scope.$digest();
  }));

  it('should reload the page with the right url', function() {
    var compiledElementScope = element.isolateScope();
    compiledElementScope.reload();
    expect(window.location.href).toEqual('/');
  });
});
```

**UPDATED**

Instead of doing any of this, I can just use `target="_self"` on links which triggers a full page reload.

Comment: Note, that you might no need to use this directive. if you want to trigger page reload on links in angular app, just add `target="_self"` attribute to them. This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11857881/1297743 still actual

Answer (score 0):

Your test would be more natural if you will trigger an event.

```
element.triggerHandler('click');
```

Then your handler will be called by internal `angular` mechanisms.

Also your test will be failed when you trying to update `window.location`, because it causes full page reload. So, you need to mock window here:

```
var fakeWindow, element, scope;
beforeEach(module('myModule'));
beforeEach(function() {
    // define fake instance for $window
    module(function($provide) {
       fakeWindow = {location: {}};
       $provide.value('$window', fakeWindow)
    });
});

beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = $compile('<a reload href="/"></a>')(scope);
    scope.$digest();
}));

it('should reload the page with the right url', function() {
   var event = jasmine.createSpyObj('clickEvent', ['preventDefault']);
   event.type = 'click';
   element.triggerHandler(event)
   expect(fakeWindow.location.href).toEqual('/');
   expect(event.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Now you can safely test your behaviour without side-effects.

Comment: Thanks. So the link function would basically look like: `element.on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $window.location.href = attrs.href; }); And the template would look like `<a ng-transclude></a>`  ??  How can I test that e.preventDefault() was called?

Comment: No, you still can use `ng-click`, and angular will create a event handler for you. See updated answer with `preventDefault` call tracking via `jasmine.createSpyObj`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just noticed @just-boris that `click.type = 'click';` should be `event.type = 'click';` for this to work for me.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Updated the answer